# What's wrong with this "if" statement?

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

I have a big problem with jquery if condition:
I have a div and if user click on it, calling ajax and user put a data and submit form.
I check the input with jQuery and if it was OK send to another ajax form.
for the first time it work and if check the conditions but for the second time if user click on div and call the first ajax then call the second ajax on submit jQuery if condition not work and send data to second ajax form even if condition was false!!!!

Note: if click on div every things work fine for the first time only and for the second time not. but if user refresh page after first submit and then click on div it works.

some part of my codes:

```
<div id="submit">submit</div>
//on click o div show the first ajax form for input
// and on submit check data and send it to second ajax
if( (val == 'A') || (val == '') ){
   //send data to ajax
} else if((cell_val != '') || (cell_val != 'A')){
   // show alert msg
}
```

I want to check if user input is something like "A" or empty then send data to ajax else show alert.

Comment: are you getting any errors? can you post your actual code for the click handler on the submit div?

Comment: you "if" is javascript, not jquery. JQuery is a framework, not a language.

Comment: Also, please don't tag with PHP and JS .. the `if` relates to one or the other, but not both (they could both be wrong, but that's two issues, not one). As far as what data comes back from AJAX (which is the only important part of PHP, use a web inspector) to rule it out as the culprit.

Comment: – MrOBrian I was adding my submit codes

Answer (score 1):

```
 if((cell_val != '') || (cell_val != '-'))
```

would always return true

use

```
if (!(cell_val == '' || cell_val=='-'))
```

instead

Comment: for the first time it work but for the second ajax call it return true

Comment: well logic makes no sense putting a if statement that always is true there... cell_val will ALWAYS be either NOT '' OR '-'

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your code, your java script is inside of html. Use `<script type='text/javascript'> your code``

In the second `if` after else you should use `&&` instead of `||`. Just on the note - `val` and `cell_val` sound so similar that I wonder if this is what you wanted... I have this doubt also based on your explanation, for if I understood you well, you don't need to use anything after `else` except displaing alert box.

Comment: val is cell-val, there is missing

Comment: I want to check if val =="A" or val== ""(empty) then send val to ajax else show alert, for the first time user call this form by ajax it work but when user click on div for second tine and call this form to add new data it return true always even false

Comment: So, please remove part of the code after `else` for you have already checked this out. You do not need to do `if (A) {} else if (!A) {}`. You simply do `if (A) {} else {}`. It does not solve your problem, but cleans the code.

Comment: What do you mean by '....add new data it return true always`? You mean no alert box is shown even though you expect to be seen or you say that ajax returns something even though you don't want it to return it?

Comment: if user submit wrong data it check the conditions and show me a alert but it not show me any alert msg and send data to ajax

Comment: BTW - I see an error in your ajax call. You have a typo `uccess` instead of `success`

Comment: for the first time you come to this page and click on div then submit data and it check conditions and if was wrong it show alert and you finished it, now you clock on div to call it again and put some new data for new submit now it not check the conditions and don't show alert and send data directly to ajax

Comment: uccess is miss spelling when type it here

Comment: You have typed in the whole text in here?! Can you copy/paste the code, so we can be sure that there is no other typo? Otherwise you may have written in here properly something you have wrong in your code and thus we will never find it.

Comment: I am taking look at the code. Please, fix also the first two blocks for they are for sure wrong. First has a mix of html and js, the second has a syntax error.

Comment: You know if i removing cell_val == '' condition, the codes work fine for  unlimited times but when add this statement the codes not work on second div call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16118/discussion-between-grzegorz-and-irplayboy)